# Regex to filter characters in middle and end of string

Tags: regex

I am trying to only select strings which have '300' in the middle of the string and '.txt' at the end using regular expressions. What would be the correct regex to use?

Comment: And what have your tried. Did you even visit the several 'cookbook' sites with regexes?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var regexp = /^.*300.*\.txt$/
console.log("Abc 300 adef.txt".match(regexp))
```

Comment: If I was trying to filter for '300' or '400' in the middle, would it be '/^.*300|400.*\.txt$/'  ?

Comment: It should be `/^.*((300)|(400)).*\.txt$/`

Comment: Recommend doing `^.*(?:300|400).*\.txt$` instead as OP didn't have the intention to capture any values. So doing non-capturing group would be more appropriate. I think even if the goal is to capture either the 300 or 400 value, the expression shouldn't have nested `()`. (300|400) is sufficient.